# netstat lots of 127.0.0.1:8080 TIME_WAIT

Tags: tomcat, networking, tcp, netstat

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633677/why-are-there-so-many-time-wait-connectings-when-using-eventmachine) post like mine but did not find as a solution.
So When I do `netstat -n` I am getting following:

```
TCP    127.0.0.1:52144        127.0.0.1:8080         TIME_WAIT
 TCP    127.0.0.1:52145        127.0.0.1:8080         TIME_WAIT
 TCP    127.0.0.1:52146        127.0.0.1:8080         TIME_WAIT
 TCP    127.0.0.1:52147        127.0.0.1:8080         TIME_WAIT
 TCP    127.0.0.1:52148        127.0.0.1:8080         TIME_WAIT
 TCP    127.0.0.1:52149        127.0.0.1:8080         TIME_WAIT
 TCP    127.0.0.1:52150        127.0.0.1:8080         TIME_WAIT
 TCP    127.0.0.1:52151        127.0.0.1:8080         TIME_WAIT
 TCP    127.0.0.1:52152        127.0.0.1:8080         TIME_WAIT
 TCP    127.0.0.1:52153        127.0.0.1:8080         TIME_WAIT
 TCP    127.0.0.1:52154        127.0.0.1:8080         TIME_WAIT
 TCP    127.0.0.1:52155        127.0.0.1:8080         TIME_WAIT
 TCP    127.0.0.1:52156        127.0.0.1:8080         TIME_WAIT
 TCP    127.0.0.1:52157        127.0.0.1:8080         TIME_WAIT
 TCP    127.0.0.1:52158        127.0.0.1:8080         TIME_WAIT
 TCP    127.0.0.1:52159        127.0.0.1:8080         TIME_WAIT
 TCP    127.0.0.1:52160        127.0.0.1:8080         TIME_WAIT
 TCP    127.0.0.1:52161        127.0.0.1:8080         TIME_WAIT
 TCP    127.0.0.1:52162        127.0.0.1:8080         TIME_WAIT
 TCP    127.0.0.1:52163        127.0.0.1:8080         TIME_WAIT
 TCP    127.0.0.1:52164        127.0.0.1:8080         TIME_WAIT
 TCP    127.0.0.1:52165        127.0.0.1:8080         TIME_WAIT
 TCP    127.0.0.1:52166        127.0.0.1:8080         TIME_WAIT
 TCP    127.0.0.1:52167        127.0.0.1:8080         TIME_WAIT
 TCP    127.0.0.1:52168        127.0.0.1:8080         TIME_WAIT
 TCP    127.0.0.1:52169        127.0.0.1:8080         TIME_WAIT
 TCP    127.0.0.1:52170        127.0.0.1:8080         TIME_WAIT
 TCP    127.0.0.1:52171        127.0.0.1:8080         TIME_WAIT
 TCP    127.0.0.1:52172        127.0.0.1:8080         TIME_WAIT
 TCP    127.0.0.1:52173        127.0.0.1:8080         TIME_WAIT
 TCP    127.0.0.1:52174        127.0.0.1:8080         TIME_WAIT
 TCP    127.0.0.1:52175        127.0.0.1:8080         TIME_WAIT
 ...
```

And many more. when I do `ping localhost:8080`, I am getting: 
`Ping request could not find host localhost:8080. Please check the name and try again.`

when I do `ping localhost`, I am getting:

```
Pinging TA52273.com [::1] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from ::1: time<1ms
Reply from ::1: time<1ms
Reply from ::1: time<1ms
Reply from ::1: time<1ms

Ping statistics for ::1:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

When I try localhost:8080 on FF I am getting empty page, just blank page.
When I try localhost:8080 on chrome I am getting:
`Oops! This link appears to be broken.
Did you mean: localhost8080.­net`

localhost:8080 is not responding.

Any idea, what might be wrong. I can start tomcat itself without a problem. but when I deploy my app that is what happening.

Comment: So you know `ping localhost:8080` is not a valid command

Comment: it is not saying it is invalid, is it? Just saying localhost:8080 is not found, which is not up. That is how I understood. is it wrong?

Comment: What I meant was that you can't draw any conclusions since the argument isn't valid. Garbage in, garbage out.

Comment: Solution to what? Too many lines in netstat? Is there an *actual* problem? Your link says it's a solution, not a problem.

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Why are there so many "TIME\_WAIT" connectings when using EventMachine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633677/why-are-there-so-many-time-wait-connectings-when-using-eventmachine)

Comment: Solution turned out to be different, Memory was not enough for tomcat to operate. That is why it was giving empty page back(or not responding at all). I started tomcat with more memory parameter and worked. Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: So your unstated problem had nothing to do with ports. You could have saved a lot of time by saying what it actually was.

Comment: @EJP If I knew what is the problem was, I would not post it here, I though those list is showing something that too many connections to server, so tomcat can not handle and giving blank page. If I knew memory problem, I would not post command line result at all.

Comment: Your problem was Tomcat giving blank pages. You didn't say so until six comments into the post. Instead you jumped to a conclusion about TIME_WAIT and started asking about that. There's a lesson there.

Comment: @EJP Thank you for helping, I have written it in my original post, Please read it. Find this line from post: `When I try localhost:8080 on FF I am getting empty page, just blank page` See history, I added this statement when I posted 1st time, not edited.

Answer (score 2):

As to the TIME_WAITs, I would not worry about it. Have a look at [this article](http://antmeetspenguin.blogspot.fi/2008/10/timewait-in-netstat.html) for more info.

As to the ping, this is incorrect:

```
ping localhost:8080
```

while this is correct:

```
ping localhost
```

i.e. do not specify a port when doing a ping.

Use e.g. `nc`, `wget` or `telnet` to verify that something is listening (to HTTP) at that port.

Now to your issue with the webapp, what is your WAR called and where have you deployed it? 
If it is e.g. `doh.war` and you've deployed it in `$CATALINA_BASE/webapps`, then you should point your browser to

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/doh
```

assuming Tomcat is listening on 8080 on localhost.

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was a lot of processes going to TCP port 111.
'chkconfig | grep nscd ' revealed that NIS cache was not running.
I enabled nscd and the problem was gone.

```
chkconfig nscd on
```

Answer (score 0):

just ping to that port and check the netstat again
the line not appear as time_wait again